# Two NPM packages pull 2 different versions of the same package - how do I fix which package uses which?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a project with 2 npm packages(let's call them A and B) that pull 2 different versions of the same npm (call it C) package with them. Now, for a reason unknown to me, when I use A and B together, version of C changes dependent on what I define first such as:

```
import { defineCustomElements as A} from '@A/A/dist/loader';
import { defineCustomElements as B} from '@B/B/dist/loader';

// This is where things are weird
// the order in which I put A() and B() below 
// somehow defines which version of C to use
A()
B()
```

**Question:**
How do I make it that A uses version of C it pulls and likewise for B?

**I tried:**
I double checked A and B pull different versions, tried Googling about how npm decides which version of duplicate dependency to use and it didn't really get me anywhere... I saw answers that mention npm-aliases - although I don't understand how to do that if C is pulled along with the A & B.

Comment: If you're developing these dependencies you might need `peerDependencies`.

Comment: @morganney I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/how-to-override-your-dependencys-dependencies/

Let's say one of your dependencies (1st level) relies on another dependency that includes outdated other dependencies (2nd level). There hasn't been an easy way to control nested dependency versions down the `node_modules` tree other than forking and fixing your first-level dependency.

```
your-project
  |_ some-module @1.0.0
      |_ another-module-which-should-be-updated @1.0.0
```

You can now specify an **overrides** property in your `package.json` to override and enforce nested dependency versions.

```json
{
  "overrides": 
  {
    "bar@2.0.0": 
    {
      "foo": "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

So the `bar` package with the version `2.0.0` would be overriden by `foo`.

Comment: Overrides are in npm versions above 8.3.0, but our projects are on 6.15.4

Comment: Since NPM 2/3/4/5/6 flatten the `node_modules` folder - perhaps you can pin the specific C version in both A and B ? Thus only one of the C versions will be promoted/hoisted by NPM to the root `node_modules` while the other C version will stay in the corresponding A or B `node_modules` folder.